# JavaFX customizing a button

Tags: css, button, javafx

iv'e tried costumazing a button to look like the picture I have I tried with css and with regular code but both didn't work.
what I tried:

```
    backToMenu.setStyle("-fx-background-image: url('/imgs/general/back_arrow_96px_2.png')");
```

and:

```
   Image backToMenuImage = new Image((getClass().getResourceAsStream("/imgs/general/back_arrow_96px_2.png")));
        ImageView backToMenuImageView = new ImageView(String.valueOf(backToMenuImage));
        backToMenu.setGraphic(backToMenuImageView);
```

the first one is out of proportion like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mluer.png

and the second one just don't work.

how do I get the button to look like the picture?

[back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLfLh.png)

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Answer (score 0):

Your second method is the right way to do it, but you need to take out the "String.valueOf(...", in the ImageView constructor, and just do "new ImageView(backToMenuImage)".  Also, you'll probably need to use the setFitHeight() and setFitWidth() methods of the ImageView to get it to fit inside the button properly.